# Upgrading angular from 9 to 12

Tags: angular, npm, angular-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade our angular application from 9 to 12 but i understnad we have to do it one release at a time so i am still stuck in step 1 from 9 to 10
I run ng update

```
@angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10 --allow-dirty -- force and then ng update @angular/material@10 --allow-dirty --force
```

and then when i compile i get lots of errors in other packages but so i do ng update for those packages too but this method doesn't seem to work well, i have been doing this for 3 days and every time i hit a dead end and start over, is there any statigy for easy fool proof way to upgrade

TIA

Comment: Did you follow the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/)?

Comment: i did and i keep getting errors in different packages

Answer (score 1):

I've recently upgraded a project from Angular from 8 to 11 and I got a lot of help from [Click Here!](https://update.angular.io/)
It might help you.

Comment: did you go one major upgrade at a time or directly from 8 to 11 ?

Comment: You need to upgrade one by one e.g. if you are at Angular 8 you have to move to Angular 9 then 10 and then 11. This is how it works

Answer (score 1):

First need to upgrade to 10 then 11 then 12...latest

You can check [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) for upgrade commands.